# Jquery Animate Image right on click event then back to the left on second click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I am trying to animate an set of images to individually move 300px right on the first click and when clicked again move 300px left back to the starting position.

What I have right now is not working. So it's either A) something wrong with my syntax or B) my images arent actually rendering at 5px.

EDIT: This fiddle is now updated with the correct code

[Jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hatsand/Yf3xW/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #wrapper {
            width: 80em;
        }

        .image {
            width: 10em;
            height: 10em;   
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            left:5px;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".image").click(function() {
            if ($('this').css('left') =='5px') {                    
                $(".image").animate({"right": "300px"},3000);
            else
                $(".image").animate({"left": "300px"},3000);    
            }
        });     
    });     
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <section id="gallery">          
            <img id="avery" class="image" src='images/OAI.jpg' alt= "On Avery Island Album Art">
            <img id="overthesea" class="image" src='images/ITAOTS.jpg' alt="In the Aeroplane Over the Sea album art">   
            <img id="beauty" class="image" src='images/beauty.jpg' alt="Beauty Demo Album Art">
            <img id="everthingIs" class="image" src='images/everythingis.jpg' alt="Eveything Is EP Album Art">
        </section>
    </div>  
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".image").click(function () {
        var th = $(this);
        if ($(th).css('left') == '5px') {
            console.log("ret");
            $(th).animate({
                "left": "300px"
            }, 3000);
        } else {
            console.log("sdffsdsff");
            $(th).animate({
                "left": "5px"
            }, 3000);
        }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Yf3xW/6/)

Comment: oh perfect, why is it that putting the (this) in a var works instead of calling it normally the way I had??

Comment: for safe side.. u can continue without putting in variable also

Answer (score 1):

You have to change `$('this')` for `$(this)`, element `this` is always without quotes.

Greetings.